# PageViewController : Determining "next" and "previous" when using Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am converting an app to use Core Data from previously just being in-memory objects. This app fetches data from a remote API and, previously, created objects in memory with an incrementing ID and I figured out which direction the user was navigating (turning pages) in based on whether this incrementing ID was getting larger or smaller. And based on that populated child view controllers (being given to the PageViewController) with the correct info. The object selection logic was in the `didFinishAnimating` pageViewController delegate method because it was only called once per page transition.

Now I'm storing some objects in Core Data and I need to know what is "next" and "previous" in order to properly set the next and previous view controllers being fed to the PageViewControllers. As before I'm fetching from a remote API but now creating Core Data managed objects based on the data retrieved from the API.

I could make my own incrementing counter field in Core Data but I wondered if there is a better way to do this? I don't want to use Core Data like a RDBMS.

More generally - how are people using Core Data to power PageViewController apps with a dynamic object collection with potentially no "last page"?

Note: This project is written in Swift.

Comment: Why not just keep links to the next and previous objects then you simply load the next or previous object depending on the direction the user is moving in.  These would be set up as relationships in Core Data

Comment: Not a bad idea. Certainly for items already seen this is an option, the difficulty is that the user could "jump" around to varying parts of a large, essentially unordered server side list that. So I'd have these individual linked series of objects and I need to decide what to do if they eventually overlap.

The core of the issue is that my source data is unordered and I'm trying to impose order on it. So I may just have to rethink my whole approach, perhaps fetching all metadata in advance.

Comment: There's no way around it. You'd like to sorted the order of the objects somehow, you need to have a field to sort it by. Whether it's the objectID, creationDate, itemOrder or anything that suits you particular needs, you will need to store that in the database. The rest is just fetching the record using a sort descriptor and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the API I am speaking to (MediaWiki category enumeration) can return results in a timestamped fashion - I can use these timestamps as a way to determine in which direction I am going. So the lessons from this is :

- See what facilities the remote API has to determine result ordering; in this case chronological ordering fit the bill.
- If the results are truly un-ordered and coming from a remote source then you'll have to apply some kind of local ordering so that paging works predictably.

Answer (score 0):

Store the results in an array.  Pass the array (and the object to display) from one view controller to the next (dependency injection).  The view controller can ask the array what index the object is at and adjust from there.

Comment: Thanks for the input - also a great idea. The issue is that the array is always being added to as results are pulled in from the remote API and without the API giving some hint as to ordering I could not guarantee that the user's path would be the same going backwards as it was going forward. However I did find a solution I'll outline in an answer I'll post below.